# How to use alarmmanager 2 times every day?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have used the following code to set alarmmanager for only one time every days, I'd like to have 2 different time to set, so 2 times every days.

My code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     getApplicationContext().getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     AlarmReceiver.class),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an interval of AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 2 :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 2, pi);
```

but if the time of the day in which you fire your alarm matters you can use two calendar objects :

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); //midday
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);//8pm for example
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

and set your alarm manager :

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer.Notification 1 is ok, notification 2 no: I've an error: PhoneStatusBar(  204): disable: < expand icons alerts ticker* system_info back home recent clock >
W/InputMethodManagerService(  149): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41279b10 attribute=null

Comment: this issue doesnt seem to be  caused by setting alarm manager code , i suggest changing the emulator you are testing it with.

Comment: @MonaCheikhna Just continuing from the wonderful answer you gave, How to fire the Alarm 3 or 4 times, at specific times every day?

Comment: you can use same logic as here if 4 times and the time doesnt matter just AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 4

Comment: this doesnt work:   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(),cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pi);  ...  only the first alrm fires and the second one doesnt

Answer (score -2):

```
void alaramStart() {
    Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBRoadcast.class);
    intent.setAction("HELLO");
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 1234567, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pintent);
}
```