# How to start AlarmService every day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an AlarmService that is initialized when the devicve boots, starts at 6 am, ends at 6 pm and repeats hourly. 
How do I make sure that it starts again after I cancel it at 6 pm?

This is my BootReceiver:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
    // assign RefreshService class
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, RefreshService.class);
    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmManagerRequestCode, alarmIntent, 0);
    // set the alarm
    // it starts at 6 am and repeats once an hour
    // elapsed_realtime is used to save ressources
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,                    firstRefresh,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
            alarmPendingIntent);
}
```

So it is initialized when the device boots and starts at 6 am (firstRefresh) and repeats hourly. 
To have it stop I would put the following into my RefreshService(lastRefresh is 6 pm in milliseconds):

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastRefresh) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, RefreshService.class);
        PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, BootReceiver.alarmManagerRequestCode, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmPendingIntent);
}
```

Appreciate y'alls help!

Comment: Just set the part where You starting the alarm in a separate class and call it in Your BOOT_COMPLETED receiver AND after canceling....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs makes sense! Thanks, will try that later and post my results as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Opiatefuchs for pointing that out:

The only thing you have to do is setting the alarm after cancelling it and setting the first time it's fired to needed time the next day.

Answer (score -1):

Use calender, AlarmManager and pendingIntent for this-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5); // For 5 AM or 6 AM
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
        new Intent(context, NewClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

here is the nice example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879448/4617458

Comment: he set inexactRepeating, it on API19 and higher near the same. He wants to start again after canceling, that was the problem....